# Make enrolled Chromebook show as "managed by" the (child) organizational unit the user belongs to

Tags: chrome-os

I am enrolling a group of Chromebooks for users in the Organizational Unit  `example.net`, which is under the parent OU `example.com`. However, when the devices are enrolled with the users email addresses, they show up as:

> Chromebook managed by example.com

(Note that's the parent OU, not the one the user is managed by.)

I can verify that the devices are showing up in the correct OU in Google's admin interface, but on the device themselves, the UI still show them as managed by the wrong OU (the root).

Other than changing the name of the top level OU (a bad option because I want different OU's to show as different) is there any way to set that text to what I need it to be?

Comment: and what is the business related question or issue in here?

Comment: @djdomi: I'm not following? The question I'm asking is the subject line. The name of the root OU is showing up in a bunch of places rather than what I need, the name of the child OU that manages the device. How do I get that child OU name to be used?

Comment: and what is the issue, that the other name is required and does not allow the original one?

Comment: @djdomi I don't understand what you are asking. The issue is that the name that actually shows up is not the name of the child OU and my requirement is that it be the child name. Despite a bunch of searching, I don't see anything that even claims to change that. It's not saying "no", I can't even find a place to make the request.